# QLowEnergyController: How to detect connection closed by peer?

Tags: android, qt

I designed an Android application using Qt. I use `QLowEnergyController` to work with a remote BLE device.

When I programmatically ask to disconnect the device (calling myself `QLowEnergyController::disconnectFromDevice()`), the signal `QLowEnergyController::disconnected()` is emited. Fine.

Now, if I turn off the BLE device (like if peer closed the connection), `QLowEnergyController::disconnected()` is not emited.

- If I wait 15 seconds, then `QLowEnergyController::disconnected()` is emitted.
- Or, if I try to access the device (reading a descriptor for instance), this fails and instantely `QLowEnergyController::disconnected()` is emitted.

Is there a way to be notified earlier that connection is lost (closed by remote device or lost because it becomes unreachable, like being too far)?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the same thing for Android version of my app. I would suggest implementing a heart beat function in your app to check connection status.

Comment: What operation the "heart beat" should do? Do you suggest reading a BLE descriptor/caracteristic? Or is there something less bandwidth consumming?